# Is there such thing as too much detail in questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounties

I asked a question over at Stackoverflow found here ([How to overlay an image or view on top of a camera captured image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260706/how-to-overlay-an-image-or-view-on-top-of-a-camera-captured-image)). I have not received any answers yet, and have even opened a bounty. Is there something wrong with the way I am asking the question? Or is there just so much detail there that nobody wants to read it?

I consider myself only an entry level developer so for me to get as far as I did by myself, I find it hard to believe that nobody out there is able to provide at least some insight. The question has only be open for 2 days, do I have unreasonable expectations to want an answer within a few days? I'm still pretty new to StackOverflow so I'm just trying to figure out what is it that I have worded / done wrong

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There certainly is such a thing - the guidelines on [sscce](http://sscce.org/) are good ones to follow.

When posting a question, in particular with code - only post the *relevant* code. If you can show the issue with a single method, don't post the whole class, for example.

The post you linked to is very long - many people will simply not read that. If you can simplify it and cut down the code to the bare essentials so people can focus on the right areas, it could help.

The images are *very* large and it is difficult to understand what is wrong - if you could annotate them (circles and arrow and a line or two on what's the issue), that would also help.

Comment: Thanks for your insight! I went through and shortened the details, as well as the code sections. Do you think its any more appealing the way it looks now? I'm not sure what you mean that the images are very large though? They are just a standard phone captured screenshot, and they clearly show the issue if one was to do a bit of reading (which is what I am having trouble getting people to do)

Comment: @Badams - Much better. My point in regards to the images is that they take quite a lot of space in the question. If you could resize them a bit it may help. And as I mentioned already - if you use an image manipulation program to highlight the issues on these photos, it would help people immediately see what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

By just glancing at the question, it does appear to be way *too* long. You should try to cut down the question to include only the absolute essentials. If anything else is needed, then whoever has the expertise to answer your question, will probably, ask for the extra details.

Even in the case of images, you should highlight and mark what you want to bring attention to.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem on the long side, but it's not so long that I can't read it all.

But I'm tending to think there are too many pictures. Could the pics be reduced?

You mention that you expected an answer by now, keep in mind that this is a somewhat specialized topic. Someone out there surely can help, but it may take some time.